# How do I handle callbacks for multiple buttons?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm pretty new to Android development and I am trying to handle multiple button clicks from a fragment class to my activity. I was able to figure out how to handle one click by creating a listener in my fragment class and then having the activity class implement that interface.

myFragment.java

```
    onResetGridListener mCallback;


    // Container activity must implement this interface
    public interface onResetGridListener
    {
        public void ResetGridClicked();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tilemap, container, false);

        Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.resetGrid_button);

        // A simple OnClickListener for our button. You can see here how a Fragment can encapsulate
        // logic and views to build out re-usable Activity components.
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                mCallback.ResetGridClicked();
            }

        });

        return view;
    }
```

This works perfectly, however I have another button in the same fragment now and many more to come so I was wondering how to handle this. Can the activity implement more than one interface (one for each button) or am I going about this the wrong way?

Thank you for your time and information

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can let your Fragment implement interface. Then it'll look like this:

```
 //init buttons somewhere
 button.setOnClickListener(this);
 anotherButton.setOnClickListener(this);

 //that's a Fragment method
 public void onClick(View v)
   {
      switch(v.getId()){
          case R.id.button1:
            doStuff();
          break;
          case R.id.button2:
            doStuff();
          break;
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

there is two methods for using listeners :

1. implementing OnClickLitener by the encapsulating Class  in this case you will have this code in the Fragment Class

   ```
   button1.setOnClickListener(this) ; 
   button2.setOnClickListener(this) ;

   // you will have to define the clickHandler:onClick
    public void onClick(View v)
      {
         switch(v.getId()){
             case R.id.button1:
               // your code here 
             break;
             case R.id.button2:
               // your code here 
             break;
         }
      }
   ```
2. Defining a listener for each button :

> 

```
 button1.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
                     // Perform action on click
                 }
             });
 button2.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
                 public void onClick(View v) {
                     // Perform action on click
                 }
             });
```

by this way you did not have to implement the onClickListener interface.